# overriden method getting called twice

Tags: php, function, oop, abstract-class, overriding

I've a code snippet

```
<?php

abstract class Testing{
    public abstract function tester();

    public function testing(){
        $this->tester();
    }
}

class Test extends Testing{
    public function tester(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->testing();
```

I'm supposed to have an output `test` but the output I'm getting is `testtest`?
Why `tester()` being called twice?

A reference [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/74w7xS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP scripting language is **case - insensitive.** (*does not apply to variables though*)

Since your `child` class does not have any constructor , the parent class constructor gets fired.

When you do this..

```
$t = new Test();
```

The parent class constructor is fired , which is `public function testing()` , (*See the name of the class matches*)

From the [**PHP Docs**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)..

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct()
>   function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a
>   parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function,
>   by the name of the class.